# visual studio c# - find all reference as lvalue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lvalue

I'm working on a c# project in VS2015. I would need to find all occurrences of a local or member variable as an lvalue, ie when the value of the variable is set or overwritten.
I know 'Find all references' and 'Find all references on code map' but these functions finds all references including rvalues as well.
Is it possible to reduce result set to lvalues?
Thanks.